# Combine TrimStart and TrimEnd for a String

Tags: c#, regex, string, c#-4.0, trim

I have a string with some letters and numbers. here an exemple :

```
OG000134W4.11
```

I have to trim all the first letters and the first zeros to get this :

```
134W4.11
```

I also need to cut the character from the first letter he will encounter to finally retreive :

```
134
```

I know I can do this with more than one "trim" but I want to know if there was an efficient way to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: You tagged this with regex, so you seem to know that's a suitable technology. Did you try it? What **did** you try? Where is your code?

Comment: +1, a proper regex will give you what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use regex.. then Linq is your friend

```
    [Test]
    public void TrimTest()
    {
        var str = "OG000134W4.11";
        var ret = str.SkipWhile(x => char.IsLetter(x) || x == '0').TakeWhile(x => !char.IsLetter(x));
        Assert.AreEqual("134", ret);
    }
```

Comment: Note that `ret` is an `IEnumerable<char>`. To get a string, use `new String(ret.ToArray())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. I'm not very accustomed with LINQ, but that line of code is perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex I would use

```
([1-9][0-9]*)[^1-9].*
```

Here is some C# code you could try

```
var input = "OG000134W4.11";
var result = new Regex(@"([1-9][0-9]*)[^1-9].*").Replace(input, "$1");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace regex
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string result = matchTest("OG000134W4.11");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static string matchTest (string input)
    {
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"([1-9][0-9]+)\w*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*");
        Match match = rx.Match(input);

        if (match.Success){
            return match.Groups[1].Value;
        }else{
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your regex wouldn't work if there was a 0 inside the number the original poster wanted to extract. i.e. OG000104W4.11 would not work